# Handle error in AngularJs if iFrame page post throws exception

Tags: angularjs, iframe, error-handling

I have a web application that needs to display dynamically created MS Word files and it has following constituents:

- A web service that returns the Word file `Stream`
- An intermediate server page that calls the web service and writes the stream to `Response`
- A web page (built in AngularJs) that collects user inputs and posts data to the intermediate page. Input also contains a file that user uploads from his computer.

From the AngularJs page, I post data to the intermediate page using a hidden `iFrame`. Entire setup works well and when the user clicks Submit and the browser duly shows Open/Save/Cancel dialog.

How do I display a message if web service throws exception? I am not able to catch it from AngularJs code.

PS: I can use the intermediate page to display the message in iFrame but then I need to clear it out when user takes another action on the form. How can I do that from AngularJs?